# Block http requests coming to Spring boot restful service running behind a Amazon ELB

Tags: spring, rest, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have a Rest service running behind a Amazon ELB . The ELB has SSL enbaled and it offloads the SSL and then calls the backend service using http.

Is there any way I can only allow http calls to the spring restful service
coming from the load balancer and any other calls directly to the rest service should be blocked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't allow requests from 0.0.0.0/0 in the instance security group.  Only allow traffic from ELB, using the ELB's security group id (sg-xxxxxxxx) instead of an IP address, in the security group rules.